# What is the best way to cleanup and recreate databricks delta table?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to cleanup and recreate databricks delta table for integration tests.

I want to run the tests on devops agent so i am using JDBC (Simba driver) but it says statement type "DELETE" is not supported.

When i cleanup the underlying DBFS location using DBFS API "rm -r" it cleans up the table but next read after recreate gives an error - A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement.

Also if i simply do DELETE from delta table on data i still see the underlying dbfs directory and the files intact. How can I clean up the delta as well as underlying files gracefully?

Comment: Did you try drop table?

Comment: @Gladiator yes that just drops the table but underlying parquet files don’t get deleted. So next time you create the table and insert the data and then do a select you see duplicates

Comment: write the new table in `overwrite` mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use VACUUM command to do the clean up. I haven't used it yet.

If you are using spark, you can use overwriteSchema option to reload the data.

If you can provide the more details on how you are using it, it would be better

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not creating an external table. There are two types of tables:

1) Managed Tables

2) External Tables (Location for dataset is specified)

When you delete Managed Table, spark is responsible for cleanup of metaData of that table stored in metastore and for cleanup of the data (files) present in that table.

But for external table, spark do not owns the data, so when you delete external table, only metadata present in metastore is deleted by spark and data (files) which were present in that table **do not get** **deleted**.

After this if you confirm that your tables are managed tables and still dropping table is not deleting files then you can use VACUUM command:

```
VACUUM <databaseName>.<TableName> [RETAIN NUM HOURS]
```

This will cleanup all the uncommitted files from table's folder.
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

path = "<Your Azure Databricks Delta Lake Folder Path>"

for delta_table in os.listdir(path):
    dbutils.fs.rm("<Your Azure Databricks Delta Lake Folder Path>" + delta_table)
```

How to find your `<Your Azure Databricks Delta Lake Folder Path>`:

Step 1: Go to `Databricks`.

Step 2: Click `Data` - `Create Table` - `DBFS`. Then, you will find your delta tables.

Answer (score -1):

The perfect steps are as follows: 
When you do a `DROP TABLE` and `DELETE FROM TABLE TABLE NAME` the following things happen in :

- **DROP TABLE** : drops your table but data still resides.(Also you can't create a new table definition with changes in schema in the same location.)
- **DELETE FROM TABLE** deletes data from table but transaction log still resides.

So, Step 1 - DROP TABLE schema.Tablename

STEP 2 - %fs rm -r `/mnt/path/where/your/table/definition/is/pointed/fileNames.parquet`

Step 3 - % fs ls make sure there is no data and also no transaction log at that location

Step 4 : NOW>!!!!! RE_RUN your **CREATE TABLE** statement with any changes you desire `UISNG delta location` `/mnt/path/where/your/table/definition/is/pointed/fileNames.parquet`

Step 5 : Start using the table and verify using %sql `desc` `formatted` `schema.Tablename`

Comment: Sorry, I am down voting because, 
2nd step does not tell me where/how to find the parquet file path.